# Constraining input arguments to a function

Tags: idris

Lets say I want to define the Fibonacci function as following function:

```
fibo : Int -> Int
fibo 1 = 1
fibo 2 = 2
fibo n = fibo (n-1) + fibo (n-2)
```

This function is obviously not total since its undefined for integers below 1, so I need to constrain the input argument somehow..

I've tried playing around with defining a new data type `MyInt`. Something along the lines:

```
-- bottom is the lower limit
data MyInt : (bottom: Int) -> (n: Int) -> Type
  where
    ...

fibo : MyInt 1 n -> Int
...
```

However I get lost rather quickly.

How can I constraint the input argument to, for example, my `fibo` function to be integer values of 1 or above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two reasons why Idris will not recognise the `fibo` function as total. Firstly, as you pointed out, it is not defined for integers less than 1, but secondly, it calls itself recursively. Although Idris is capable of recognising the totality of recursive functions, it can generally only do so when it can be shown that the argument to the recursive call is 'smaller' (i.e. closer to a base case*) than the original argument (for example, if a function receives a list as an argument, it can call itself with the tail of the list without necessarily sacrificing totality, because the tail is a substructure of the original list and thus closer to `Nil`). The problem with expressions like `(n-1)` and `(n-2)`, when they are of type `Int`, is that although they are *numerically* smaller than n, they are not *structurally* smaller, because `Int` is not inductively defined and so has no base cases. Therefore the totality checker is unable to satisfy itself that the recursion will always eventually reach a base case (even though it might seem obvious to us), and so it will not consider `fibo` to be total.

First off, let's solve the recursion problem. Instead of `Int`, we can use an inductively-defined datatype such as `Nat`:

```
data Nat =
  Z | S Nat
```

(A natural number is either zero, or the successor of another natural number.)

This allows us to rewrite `fibo` as:

```
fibo : Nat -> Int
fibo (S Z)     = 1
fibo (S (S Z)) = 2
fibo (S (S n)) = fibo (S n) + fibo n
```

(Note how in the recursive case, instead of calculating `(n-1)` and `(n-2)` explicitly, we produce them by pattern matching on the argument, thereby demonstrating to Idris that they are structurally smaller.)

This new definition of `fibo` is still not entirely total, though, because it lacks a case for `Z` (i.e. zero). If we don't want to provide for such a case, then we need to give Idris some assurance that it will not be allowed to occur. One way we can do this is to require a proof that the argument to `fibo` is greater than or equal to one (or equivalently, one is less than or equal to the argument):

```
fibo : (n : Nat) -> LTE 1 n -> Int
fibo Z LTEZero impossible
fibo Z (LTESucc _) impossible
fibo (S Z) _ = 1
fibo (S (S Z)) _ = 2
fibo (S (S (S n))) _ = fibo (S (S n)) (LTESucc LTEZero) + fibo (S n) (LTESucc LTEZero)
```

`LTE 1 n` is the type whose values are proofs that 1 ≤ *n* (within the natural numbers). `LTEZero` represents the axiom that zero ≤ any natural number, and `LTESucc` represents the rule that if *n ≤ m*, then (successor of *n*) ≤ (successor of *m*). The `impossible` keyword indicates that a given case cannot occur. In the above definition, it is impossible for the first argument to `fibo` to be zero because there is no way to prove that 1 ≤ 0. For any other natural number n, we can prove that 1 ≤ *n* using `(LTESucc LTEZero)`.

Now at last `fibo` is total, but it's rather cumbersome to have to provide it with an explicit proof that its argument is greater than or equal to 1. Luckily, we can mark the proof argument as auto implicit:

```
fibo : (n : Nat) -> {auto p : LTE 1 n} -> Int
fibo Z {p = LTEZero} impossible
fibo Z {p = (LTESucc _)} impossible
fibo (S Z) = 1
fibo (S (S Z)) = 2
fibo (S (S (S n))) = fibo (S (S n)) + fibo (S n)
```

Idris will now automatically find a proof that 1 ≤ *n* where possible, otherwise we will still be required to provide one ourselves.

---

<sub>* There may well be some codata-related subtleties that I'm glossing over here without realising, but this is the broad principle.</sub>